# Why does `use GD::Graph::pie;` fail even though CPAN says that GD::Graph::pie is installed and up to date?

Tags: perl, gd, gd-graph

I'm trying to run a script called [honeydsum.pl](https://github.com/DataSoft/Honeyd/blob/master/scripts/misc/honeydsum-v0.3/honeydsum.pl). It is failing a test and insisting I do not have GD::Graph::pie installed. The test that fails is:

```
unless (eval "use GD::Graph::pie; 1") {
   die "$program_name: please install GD::Graph::pie.";
}
```

Thus it gives the output:

> honeydsum.pl: please install GD::Graph::pie. at ./honeydsum.pl line 65

Where I am confused is that when I check on CPAN it says GD::Graph::pie is up to date:

```
cpan[5]> install GD::Graph::pie
GD::Graph::pie is up to date (1.21).
```

I'm not a Perl expert, but is there a reason it would fail the test even if the module is installed?

Output from cpan -D:

```
~# cpan -D GD::Graph::pie
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 06 Mar 2017 21:17:02 GMT
GD::Graph::pie
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (no description)
    R/RU/RUZ/GDGraph-1.54.tar.gz
    /root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/GD/Graph/pie.pm
    Installed: 1.21
    CPAN:      1.21  up to date
    Ruslan U. Zakirov (RUZ)
    Ruslan.Zakirov@gmail.com
```

There was no output from

```
perl -MGD::Graph::pie -e1
```

In my /usr/share/  directory I have the following related to perl:

- perl/5.22
- perl/5.22.2
- perl5

I'm not sure what a proper perl installation would have put in this directory.

Comment: What happens if you try to load the module using `perl -MGD::Graph::pie -e1`?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Screenshots are inaccessible to people with visual impairment, can't be searched, and force people to re-type the text by hand when they want to run the code on their own systems or google for error messages.

Comment: The script has `/usr/bin/perl` in the shebang. Do you have another perl installed? If not, it sounds like GD::Graph::pie was installed somewhere outside of the system perl directories. What does `cpan -D GD::Graph::pie` show?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks for the edit and pointing that out. I hadn't thought about all of that. To your output from cpan, I've made the edit above.

Comment: @duskwuff There was no output from that command.

Comment: You can get why the `eval` failed with `$@`, it's like `$!` for `eval`. Also there's no need to use string eval, `eval { require GD::Graph::pie; GD::Graph::pie->import }` works. Though a constant string is safe, it's bad to get into the habit of using string eval when you don't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is using the system perl, but you installed GD::Graph::pie for a perlbrew installation. If you want the script to use your perlbrew perl, change the shebang from

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -T -w
```

to

```
#! /root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/bin/perl -T -w
```